# Place a String separated by commas into the Excel rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, mysql, csv

I have a String like this separated by the commas:

`id, payment_request_id, user_id, market_id, exchange_id, type_id, nominal, ask_price, original_rate, min_execution, from_date, to_date, state, pause_no_credit, activated_at, shadow_order_id, executable_nominal, ioc_order_id, easy_order, limit_left`

I would like to delete the commas and turn that into a row so I can paste in the top of this data file:

[image]

This will be very helpful as I have quite a few files. These data came from MySQL DB as CSV format and I turned them into Excel with a hope I can better analysis them.

Comment: Your question and Screen shot conflicts each other. please be specific. What I'm understanding that you want comma separated values into Rows. Like ID, user_id are initially in cell, you want to place ID in one row and user_id on different, like A1 & A2 , am I correct? Please confirm. or simply you need to place them in columns !

Comment: Sorry I’m one row that is formed with Columns. The value inside the column cells needs to be the values separated by commas.

Comment: This is solve now ... see the answer

Comment: The below shown answer shows you need to place them in Columns ! Nice, Keep asking.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the way to do this. It can be easily achievable with the `data -> text to column` option in the Excel.

[image]